# query SMS inbox always return null value in Realme

Tags: java, android, sms

I wrote a code to get SMS from android. Use `content://sms/inbox` but it's alway return null.

**main**

```
public void getAllSmsFromProvider() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

    if (!smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return; // smsInboxCursor always return null

    // loop through the messages in inbox
    do {
        // get the value based on the index of the column
        String address = smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
        String body = smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        long date = smsInboxCursor.getLong(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date"));

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllSmsFromProvider: " + address + " - " + date + " - " + body);

    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

    smsInboxCursor.close();
}
```

**manifests**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

I have checked the permissions before using this code. But `smsInboxCursor` always return null.

**permissions**

```
private void checkPermissionSMS() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_SMS);
    } else {
        getAllSmsFromProvider();
    }
}
```

error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trantien.xxx/com.trantien.xxx.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
```

**edit:I checked my code, and It has errors when running on Realme. But when I tried it on another device, it worked fine. I don't understand :((**

Comment: Have you asked user for sms permission at runtime? Declaring permissions in manifest is not enough

Comment: @Pawel i asked permission and user agrees to allow Read SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below classes for getting SMS:

```
SmsFromDevice smsFromDevice = new SmsFromDevice(mContext, SmsDetailsActivity.this);
ArrayList<SmsRetriveModel> smsRetrieveModels = smsFromDevice.getSMSofNumber(numberToGetSms, "All", "1469385000000");
Log.d(TAG,smsRetrieveModels.size());
```

You can change "1469385000000" lastSyncDate.

**SmsFromDevice.java**

```
   class SmsFromDevice {

    private static final String TAG = SmsFromDevice.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private String numberToGetSms = "";
    private ArrayList<SmsRetriveModel> arrSmsDetails;

    SmsFromDevice(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    //type: Inbox|All  //no:(eg:9898989898) //lastSyncDate in milliseconds
    ArrayList<SmsRetriveModel> getSMSofNumber(String no, String type, String lastSyncDate) {
        numberToGetSms = no;
        if (checkSMSPermission()) {
            final ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

            Uri myMessage = null;
            if (type.equals("Inbox")) {
                myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            } else if (type.equals("All")) {
                myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            }

            String filter = "date> " + lastSyncDate + " and address='" + numberToGetSms + "'";

            Cursor curSms = contentResolver.query(myMessage, null, filter, null, "date DESC");
            if (curSms.getCount() > 0) {
                arrSmsDetails = getSmsInModel(curSms);
                curSms.close();
            } else {
                Log.e("===NULL", "SMS not found!!Cursor null...");
            }
        } else {
            getSMSPermission();
        }
        return arrSmsDetails;
    }

    private ArrayList<SmsRetriveModel> getSmsInModel(Cursor c) {

        try {
            arrSmsDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
                        c.moveToNext();
                        continue;
                    }
                    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                    LogUtils.logD("===NUMBER", "" + number);

                    SmsRetriveModel smsRetriveModel = new SmsRetriveModel();

                    String dateInMilli = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    String msgBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(dateInMilli)));

                    smsRetriveModel.setSmsMilliSec(dateInMilli);
                    smsRetriveModel.setMobileNo(numberToGetSms);
                    smsRetriveModel.setSmsBody(msgBody);
                    smsRetriveModel.setSmsDate(dateFormatted);

                    arrSmsDetails.add(smsRetriveModel);
                    //}
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.logE(TAG, e);
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }

        return arrSmsDetails;
    }


    private boolean checkSMSPermission() {

        String permission = "android.permission.READ_SMS";
        int res = mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void getSMSPermission() {
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (version >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale");
                }
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SmsRetriveModel.java**

```
public class SmsRetriveModel {

    private String mobileNo,smsDate,smsSender,smsBody,smsMilliSec;

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public String getSmsDate() {
        return smsDate;
    }

    public void setSmsDate(String smsDate) {
        this.smsDate = smsDate;
    }

    public String getSmsSender() {
        return smsSender;
    }

    public void setSmsSender(String smsSender) {
        this.smsSender = smsSender;
    }

    public String getSmsBody() {
        return smsBody;
    }

    public void setSmsBody(String smsBody) {
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    }

    public String getSmsMilliSec() {
        return smsMilliSec;
    }

    public void setSmsMilliSec(String smsMilliSec) {
        this.smsMilliSec = smsMilliSec;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check full answer

Comment: I tried to run your code but it didn't work (or I installed it wrongly).
After a while of checking my code, it only had an error on the Realme device.
When I try it with another device (samsung), it works normally

Comment: i have checked it with Samsung and Oneplus device. I will try to test it in Realme device,

Comment: in Realme, this morning I tried to run normally, after about 2 hours of opening the app again bugs.

Comment: i will try to check in Realme